# What is the syntax for Python 2.7 to permanent display in percent in a field column?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

What is the syntax to build to calculate field, for example,

Acres to Percent?

841173.00 to 82 %

What I want the field column in Percent to be display numbers with  percent with the alignment to the right of 2 characters? How is that possible?

I can run from the Calculate field toolbox and then use the Field Calculator and insert the expression with the python syntax.

[image: Example of from Acres to Percent]

I had to manually right click on the Percent field column's properties to get to the Percentage under the Number Format and change it from there. I feel this is a time-consumed for me because I will be doing this for about 80 of them. I want to get the expression and let it run from the Calculate Field.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What is the percentage based on? If it is based on an existing value, then I'm not sure why you would need python for this. As you indicate, you can just use the field calculator and format it as a percentage. What information am I missing?

Comment: This would be better as a comment to the original question, rather than an answer.

Comment: Good point. I don't see how I can edit it as such.

Comment: Why would someone downvote on me ? I was trying to ask someone to help me and others comment on my question. Thank you for downvote one me That just shows disrespect me. If you don't understand someone Ask first before you downvote.

Comment: @PROBERT, it's likely because this question is primarily  python related, not ArcMap specific (look no further than the title). It's not disrespectful to downvote questions. As it stands, this question doesn't appear to have much in relation to GIS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new field (text)
2. In field calculator, round the original `Percent` value to no decimals, and append a percent sign:

   - `format(round(!Percent!)) + "%"`
   - or the shorter, more elegant `"{}%".format(round(!Percent!))`

(*Thanks to Paul for the improved syntax!*)

Comment: Would that work in Model Builder ?

Comment: Why wrap `int(!Percent!)` in `format()` instead of `str()`? Or, the simpler `"{}%".format(int(!Percent!))`.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `round()` instead of `int()`.

Comment: @Paul -- my Python syntax is still a work in progress, I appreciate the suggestions :)

Comment: @PROBERT -- Yes, following more or less the same workflow as in [this other answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107283/how-do-i-force-the-comma-into-acres-number-on-the-modelbuilder/107284#107284)

Comment: the round sytanx seems to work however not where I want the decimal should be...

Comment: @PROBERT if you want one decimal place (e.g.), use `"{}%".format(round(!Percent!, 1))`

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out here from this site...but I guess I did the wrong place...https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: The decimal place selection (1, 2, none, etc.) has to happen before the number is converted to a string. [This is the relevant Python doc page.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)